# Make buttons (or checkbox) and copy values from them to make a list of values

Tags: copy-paste

I need to make a simple app with TV programs, names on buttons or checkboxes, and when i click multiple buttons (or select checkboxes) it copies values from them to a textarea that I can then copy and use elsewhere.

For example, I might have 5 buttons, named MTV, MTV2, FOX, CNN, ZDF. When I click for example on 3 of those (MTV, FOX, MTV2) I get in an text area following: MTV; FOX; MTV2 (so I can copy that desired list of TV programs).

I found the code in HTML (below), but I don't know how to make TV program to stay in textarea, each time I click new TV program, it only shows that program - it does not make a list of programs.

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function(){<!--  w w  w. j a  v a2  s.  c  om-->
         $("button").click(function () {
         var text = $(this).text();
         $("input").val(text);
         });
         });
      </script>
      <style>
         .selected { color:red; }
         .highlight { background:yellow; }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div>
         <button>HRT1</button>
         <button>HRT2</button>
         <button>NovaTV</button>
         <button>NovaTV</button>
         <button>NovaTV</button>
         <button>NovaTV</button>
         <button>NovaTV</button>
         <button>NovaTV</button>
         <button>NovaTV</button>
         <button>NovaTV</button>
         <button>NovaTV</button>
         <button>NovaTV</button>
         <button>NovaTV</button>
         <button>NovaTV</button>
         <button>NovaTV</button>
         <button>NovaTV</button>
         <button>NovaTV</button>
      </div>
      <input type="text" value="click a button" />
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. You need to concatenate the text with each line on each click to preserve it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var textForInput= "";

$("button").click(function () {
    var text = $(this).text();

    textForInput = textForInput.concat(text + " ");
    $("input").val(textForInput);
});
});
</script>
<style>
.selected { color:red; }
.highlight { background:yellow; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<button>HRT1</button>
<button>HRT2</button>
<button>NovaTV</button>
<button>NovaTV</button>
<button>NovaTV</button>
<button>NovaTV</button>
<button>NovaTV</button>
<button>NovaTV</button>
<button>NovaTV</button>
<button>NovaTV</button>
<button>NovaTV</button>
<button>NovaTV</button>
<button>NovaTV</button>
<button>NovaTV</button>
<button>NovaTV</button>
<button>NovaTV</button>
<button>NovaTV</button>
</div>
<input type="text" value="click a button" />
</body>
</html>
```